# Moving information from an Excel file into a Word document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am coding in VBA in Excel. I have an Excel sheet with information. I have two sheets titled: `Finance` and `Invoice`. I want to the `Finance` page to have cells which I would fill out - just by typing in the cells. And then I want the `Invoice` page to have specific cells which are auto-populated from the information in the `Finance` sheet.

Then, I want the cells on the `Invoice` page to be moved into a Word document. I am using a macro I've titled `Macro2`.

In the top part of the code, I am copying information from cells in the `Finance` sheet into the `Invoice` sheet. That works. But then I am trying to take the filled out information in the `Finance` sheet and move it into a Word doc. I looked for code online - but it isn't working for me. The cells that I want to move into a Word doc are `B1` through `D19` on the `Invoice` page. The name of my Excel file is FinanceMarketing.

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
    'Ask user for input
    userinput = InputBox("Type Associated Letter corresponding to Desired Invoice Population:")
    'Copy Name
    Sheets("Finance").Range("B2").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Invoice").Range("D3")
    'Copy Email
    Sheets("Finance").Range("C2").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Invoice").Range("D4")
    'Copy Adress
    Sheets("Finance").Range("D2").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Invoice").Range("D5")
    'Copy Date
    Sheets("Finance").Range("E2").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Invoice").Range("B8")
    'Copy Amount Owed
    Sheets("Finance").Range("I2").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Invoice").Range("D8")

    
    'From here down in the part of the code that I found online to move the excel into word which isn't working   
'Using Early Binding

    Dim wordApp As Word.Application
    Dim mydoc As Word.Document    

    'Creating a new instance of word only if there no other instances
    Set wordApp = New Word.Application   

    'Making word App Visible
    wordApp.Visible = True

    'Creating a new document
    Set mydoc = wordApp.Documents.Add()

    'copying the content from excel sheet
    FinanceMarketing.Worksheets("Invoice").Range("B1:D19").Copy

    'Pasting on the document
    mydoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteExcelTable _
                               LinkedToExcel:=False, _
                               WordFormatting:=False, _
                               RTF:=False

    'saving the document
    mydoc.SaveAs2 "MyDoc"

    'closing the document
    'mydoc.Close
   
    'Emptying the Clipboard
    'CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Help to get moving the info into word would be very appreciated!

Comment: [*"It's not working"* is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). Please give a good error description or describe what your code does versus what you expected it to do.

Comment: Sorry about that! I am getting a pop-up that says "Can't execute code in break mode".

Comment: No, that's not your error. *"Can't execute code in break mode"* is shown if VBA is halted (due to a breakpoint or a runtime error) and you try to execute another macro. That said: I assume that **a)** you don't use `Option Explicit` (why not???) and **b)** `FinanceMarketing` is undefined and you get an *"error 424 Object required"*